# Drawing $(x(t),y(t))=(cos(t),sin(t))$ on the $(x,y)$ plane over various domains

Tags: calculus

Observe the system where $x$ and $y$ are both real valued maps: $\left\{ \begin{array}{lr} x’(t)=-y(t), \\ y’(t)=x(t) \end{array}\right.$

Clearly, $x(t)=cos(t)$ and $y(t)=sin(t)$ satisfy the given system. It’s also clear on how to draw $(x(t),y(t)=(cos(t),sin(t)$ on the $(x,y)$ such that $t \in [0,\pi]$ and $t \in [0,2\pi]$. The first domain yields a half circle while the second domain yields a full circle; both centered at $0$, of course.

However I was thinking of some other domains to draw $(x(t),y(t)=(cos(t),sin(t)$ over: what would $t\in [0,\infty)$ and $t\in (-\infty,\infty)$ look like? I tried plotting these both in Desmos and MATLAB and was unable to get any meaningful results. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically drawing the same circle over and over again.

Comment: If your domain is an interval whose length is longer than $2\pi$ (including possibly unbounded intervals), then you will definitely get the entire circle.

Comment: @trisct So would you only have one circle? Or concentric circles with increasing radii?

Comment: Only one circle. $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $t\in[2\pi,4\pi]$ correspond to the same circle (unit circle). If you draw $t\in[0,2\pi]$ you get the entire circle, if you continue to draw $t\in[2\pi,4\pi]$ you draw the exact same circle again.

Comment: @trisct gotcha! So would $t\in [0, \infty)$ be a half circle over and over again such as what described for the full circle?

Comment: $t\in[0,\infty)$ is still an entire circle, since after drawing $t\in[0,2\pi]$ you already have an entire circle.